# Error returning MONGO data through JAX-RS

Tags: java, mongodb, jax-rs

I am trying to  query document from mongodb and return it as JSON. But when I hit the url it gives me internal server error saying-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
```

How can I fix it ? I am using "mongo-java-driver-3.0.3.jar"
I have been using same jar file for non-web projects and it runs fine.
Code:

```
 @Path("/UserService")
 public class UserService {

UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getUsers(){
   List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

   MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

   FindIterable<Document> iterable= db.getCollection("test").find(new Document("_id","1234")).projection(new Document("_id",0));
   iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {

       public void apply(final Document document) {
        list.add(document.toJson());

       }
   });
   mongoClient.close();




  return list;
  } 
}
```

Comment: If using maven add dependency <dependency>
 <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
 <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>       or download jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/3.0.0 and add as external jar to your project

Comment: @Anvesh Vejandla I am not using maven. I already tried adding bson jar file, but still I am getting the same error.  I can see bson.connversions.Bson class even in mongo-java-driver. Still it is throwing the error at run time.

Comment: Add the jar in your class path